# Private function in Javascript constructor is not accessible publicly

Tags: javascript, object

I have this person object

```
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;

    function sayName(){
        var full="";    
        full="Hello my name is "+this.firstName + " "+this.lastName;
    }
}
```

and have made an instance of this object

```
var raul = new person("Raul","Zamora","19","brown")
```

I cannot figure out why the function sayName is not working. I am implementing it as such:

```
document.getElementById("sayName").innerHTML=raul.sayName();
```

where `sayName` is already defined as an id on the HTML part.

Comment: Also: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: FYI it's good practice to capitalise constructor names (e.g. `Person`).

Comment: Maybe the following can help you understand constructor functions and prototype: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because that `sayName` function is only visible in the scope of the constructor (and thus is totally useless).

To make that function available on instances, use

```
person.prototype.sayName = function(){
   var full="Hello my name is "+this.firstName + " "+this.lastName;
   return full; // don't forget to return the string
}
```

For more details, I suggest this article from the MDN : [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: or inside the constructor, `this.sayName = function() ...`

Comment: @Bart In this case, as it uses `this`, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Bart I explained it below the other answer : it's useless to create a function for every instance. Please have a look at the documentation I link to.

Comment: As I've explained in that answer, there's definitely a use case for doing it per instance: private members. Whether you personally prefer the closure pattern vs the prototype pattern is entirely your opinion, and not by definition a "bad" idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `sayName` does not "belong" to your Class, in order to do so you need to declare it using `this` or using `propotype`

Using `this` :

```
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
            this.sayName = function(){
                return "Hello my name is "+this.firstName + " "+this.lastName;
            }
        }
```

Using `prototype` :

```
person.prototype.sayName = function(){
     return "Hello my name is "+this.firstName + " "+this.lastName;
}
```

Additionally `sayName` was not returning anything.

Comment: This construct builds a different function for every instance. It's better to use the prototype.

Comment: @dystroy "better" is subjective. Performance may not be important here, and this pattern is the only pattern that allows true private members, in case you'd need it.

Comment: @Bart where do you see a private member here ?

Comment: @dystroy Well, 3 edits ago he was using `firstName` instead of `this.firstName`...

Comment: I guess you mean `person.prototype.sayName` (with `prototype`).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a local function declaration there. Make it a property of the object by assignment - just like you did write [`this.firstName = first` not `var firstName = first`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572).

This will make it a method that is accessible from outside:

```
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;

    this.sayName = function sayName(){
        var full="Hello my name is "+this.firstName + " "+this.lastName;
    };
}
```

However, some objections:

- Constructor names should be capitalized
- Your `sayName` method needs to `return` the string, or your example invocation won't work
- Using the prototype for values that can be shared amongst instances (such as methods) [is preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572)

So we get to

```
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
Person.prototype.sayName = function sayName(){
    return "Hello my name is "+this.firstName + " "+this.lastName;
};
```

```
var raul = new Person("Raul","Zamora","19","brown");
document.getElementById("sayName").textContent = raul.sayName();
```